# Query from in elastic search from specific item id

Tags: database, elasticsearch, nosql

In my system, items (they are like blog posts), are published often.
In the main page I list 20 items, and there is a Load More button at the bottom, which will take the next 20 items. If I wait a while, there will be new blog posts in elastic, so If I click Load More, it will take the 20 items from 20 to 40, but there are new ones so it returns some items repeated.

The question is: how could I part from the last item published to paginate and get the next 20 items from that one? Like ignoring there are new items

I thought about making a query first to get the position (if there is a way to know the position of a specific item in a query) but it would be making the query twice.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this kind of cursor based pagination in elasticsearch: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html

[EDIT]
This is what in the end worked for me
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html